# tasks.json exists but 'No task defined'

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I have a tasks.json open in VSCode. When I try to 'Run Task' I get 'No task to be run. Configure Tasks'.

Trying to Configure Tasks I get 'Open tasks.json'. But tasks.json is already open in VSCode. Closing tasks.json and reopening it gives the same result.

Help appreciated. tasks.json shown below.

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
   "label": "GnuCOBOL - Compile (single file)",
   "type": "shell",
   "options": {
    "env": {
        "PATH":"\\gnucobol3\\bin",
        "COB_CONFIG_DIR": "c:\\gnucobol3\\config",
        "COB_COPY_DIR": "c:\\gnucobol3\\copy",
        "COB_INCLUDE_PATH": "c:\\gnucobol3\\include",
        "COB_LIB_PATH": "c:\\gnucobol3\\lib",
       },
    "command": "cobc",
    "args": [
      "-x",
      "-std=mf",
      "-t${fileBasenameNoExtension}.LST",
      "${file}"
      ]
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `tasks.json` file got changed.  It should be of this form:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",

  // "global" options can go here

  "options": {
    "env": {
        "APP_NAME": "Nice"
    }
  },

  // you are missing the tasks array

  "tasks": [

    {                             // task 1
            "label": "Task A",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo A2",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "presentation": {
                "group": "groupA"
            }
            // or task-specific options can go here
        },
        {                         //  task 2
            "label": "Task B",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "echo B",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "presentation": {
                "group": "groupA"
            }
        }
   ]
}
```

So with your code:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "options": {
    "env": {
      "PATH":"\\gnucobol3\\bin",
      "COB_CONFIG_DIR": "c:\\gnucobol3\\config",
      "COB_COPY_DIR": "c:\\gnucobol3\\copy",
      "COB_INCLUDE_PATH": "c:\\gnucobol3\\include",
      "COB_LIB_PATH": "c:\\gnucobol3\\lib",
     }
    },

    "tasks": [
       {
          "label": "GnuCOBOL - Compile (single file)",
          "type": "shell",
          "command": "cobc",
          "args": [
            "-x",
            "-std=mf",
            "-t${fileBasenameNoExtension}.LST",
            "${file}"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to respond - my response is too big for a comment.

Mark: I've modified tasks.json thus but still get same errors:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",

    {
      "label": "GnuCOBOL - Compile (single file)",
      "type": "shell",
      "options": {
        "env": {
          "PATH":"\\gnucobol3\\bin",
          "COB_CONFIG_DIR": "c:\\gnucobol3\\config",
          "COB_COPY_DIR": "c:\\gnucobol3\\copy",
          "COB_INCLUDE_PATH": "c:\\gnucobol3\\include",
          "COB_LIB_PATH": "c:\\gnucobol3\\lib",
        },
        "tasks": [
         {"command": "cobc",
          "args": [
           "-x",
           "-std=mf",
           "-t${fileBasenameNoExtension}.LST",
           "${file}"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `label` and `type` are parts of each task.

Comment: "Not sure how to respond"
Answer: edit your question with an new "update" part (please delete the 2 non-answers you've posted).
And if @Marks answer worked for you please mark it as solution + upvote

Answer (score 0):

Mark: your mods now run but with errors:

```
> Executing task: cobc -x -std=mf -ttasks.LST c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json <

c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:2: error: invalid indicator 'e' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:3: error: invalid indicator 'o' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:4: error: invalid indicator 's' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:5: error: invalid indicator 'i' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:6: error: invalid indicator 'n' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:7: error: invalid indicator '"' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:8: error: invalid indicator '"' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:9: error: invalid indicator '"' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:10: error: invalid indicator '"' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:11: error: invalid indicator '"' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:14: error: invalid indicator 'k' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:16: error: invalid indicator '"' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:17: error: invalid indicator '"' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:18: error: invalid indicator '"' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:19: error: invalid indicator '"' at column 7
c:\WORKAREA\cobol\VisualStudioCode\.vscode\tasks.json:24: error: invalid indicator ']' at column 7
```

Comment: But strangely enough my program compiles correctly.